# Image download link - OpenERP

Tags: image, download, odoo, attachment

I am looking for a way to add a download link on a form view in OpenERP such that when I click the link, I can download a previously uploaded image. What would be the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Hassan Zaheer

If you use the fields.binary then you can have that feature, when you use the binary field do not use the any widget with the field and you will notice that odoo will convert your uploaded image in to url which you can click and download.

Here example of self calculating binary field.

```
import base64
from osv import osv, fields

class my_class(osv.osv_memory):

    def get_file(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name=None, arg=None, context=None):
        result = dict.fromkeys(ids)
        for record_browse in self.browse(cr, uid, ids):
            f = open(record_browse.file_path)
            result[record_browse.id] = base64.encodestring(f.read())
            f.close()
        return result

    _name = 'my.class'

    _columns = {
        'file_path': fields.char('File Location', size=128),
        'file': fields.function(get_file, method=True, store=False, type='binary', string="Download File"),
    }
```

or  you can add simple field.binary like :

```
'filedata': fields.binary('Label',filters='*.xml'),
```

And add the field on view that will show as downloadable url.

Comment: what is filters='*.xml' in binary field definition?

Comment: When I do that, the download image is not in png format. Whenver I try open the downloaded file, I have to select that through which program I want to open it.